# Multiline regular expression in Autoit3

Tags: html, regex, autoit, pcre

I am trying to match multi-line HTML source code with a regular expression (using AutoIt). HTML source code to match:

```
<li class="mission">
    <div>
        <div class="missionTitle">
            <h3>Eat a quarter-pounder with cheese</h3>
            <div class="missionProgress">
                <span>100%</span>
                <div class="missionProgressBar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="missionDetails">
            <ul class="missionRewards">
                <li class="rewardCash">5,000&ndash;8,000</li>
                <li class="rewardXP">XP +5</li>
                                </ul>
                            <div class="fightItems clearfix">
                <h5><span>Prerequisites:</span></h5>
                                    <div class="fightItemsWrap">
                                            <div class="fightItem tooltip" title="Sunglasses" data-attack="Attack: 2" data-defence="Defence: 2">
                        <img src="/img/enhancement/3.jpg" alt="">
                        <span>&times; 1</span>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="fightItem tooltip" title="Broad Shoulders" data-attack="Attack: 0" data-defence="Defence: 3">
                        <img src="/img/enhancement/1003.jpg" alt="">
                        <span>&times; 1</span>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="fightItem tooltip" title="Irish Fond Anglia" data-attack="Attack: 4" data-defence="Defence: 8">
                        <img src="/img/enhancement/2004.jpg" alt="">
                        <span>&times; 1</span>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
            </div>
                            <form action="/quest/index/i/kdKJBrgjdGWKqtfDrHEkRM2duXVn1ntH/h/c0b2d58642cd862bfad47abf7110042e/t/1336917311" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="17"/>
                <button class="button buttonIcon btnEnergy"><em>5</em></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

It is present multiple times on a single page (but items within `<div class="fightItems clearfix">...</div>` vary).

- I need to match

  - `<h3>Eat a quarter-pounder with cheese</h3>`,
  - the first span `<span>100%</span>` and
  - `<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="17"/>`.

Expected result (for every occurrence on a page):

```
$a[0] = "Eat a quarter-pounder with cheese"
$a[1] = "100%"
$a[2] = "17"
```

What I came up with:

```
(?U)(?:<div class="missionTitle">\s+<h3>(.*)</h3>\s+<div class="missionProgress">\s+<span>(.*)</span>)|(?:<form .*\s+.*<input\stype="hidden"\sid="id"\sname="id"\svalue="(\d+)"/>\s+.*\s+</form>)
```

But that leaves some array-items empty. I also tried the `(?s)` flag, but then it only captures first occurrence (and stops matching after).

Comment: I'm not familiar with autoit, but have a look if it has some html/xml support. You'll be much better off using a proper parser.

Comment: Next time, I wouldn't use a regular expression for this purpose. But rather a for loop that iterates on each line of the string and takes action based on whether or not a certain substring is there. It's a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I had not to use `.` to match words or integers, because of the `(?s)` flag. The correct regex is:

```
(?U)(?s)<div class="missionTitle">\s+<h3>([\w\s]+)</h3>(?:.*)<div class="missionProgress">\s+<span>(\d+)%</span>(?:.*)<input.* value="(\d+)"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression to match multi-line HTML source code:

- As per [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm);

  - `\R` matches newline characters `(?>\r\n|\n|\r)`,
  - dot `.` does not (unless `(?s)` is set).
  - `\s` matches white space characters.
- Generally some combination is required (like `\R\s*?`).
- Non-capturing groups are redundant (match without capturing instead).
- If uniquely enclosed, single characters may be excluded instead (like `attribute="([^"]*?)"` for text between double-quotes).

Example (contains double-quotes; treat as per [Documentation - FAQ - double quotes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/faq.htm#3)):

```
(?s)<div class="missionTitle">.*?<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?<div class="missionProgress">.*?<span>([^<]*?)</span>.*?<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="([^"]*?)"/>
```

Visual explanation:

[image: Regular expression image]
[image: Regular expression image]

If regular expressions should be used on HTML (beyond simple listings like this) is a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (been, done, [T-shirt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/help-design-our-stack-overflow-t-shirts/35432#35432)).